# Can we rename REDIS index?

Tags: redis

I am trying to configure REDIS for our upcoming upgrade and wanted to use the different index for different objects types -ex. 0 for user objects, 1 for user data etc. and was wondering if there is any way to rename the default index number to something which developer can remember e.g. user, posts...

This might help prevent accidental usage of wrong index.

Answer (score 2):

Redis db are identified by an integer. there's no concept of db name. So the answer is NO. it is not possible.